# camera for micro robots

Tags: ros, slam, navigation, camera, robot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Ros community,

My group are planning to build a micro size robots with max weight of 500g. We want to buy a camera or cameras that can be use to find object and latter on to have it operate autonomously. Also, hopefully we can use SLAM with it.
Any suggestions?

Update: Also, is there a small camera that can be use to identify a target?

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/218150/camera-for-micro-robots/) by [Vinh K](https://answers.ros.org/users/23017/vinh-k/) on ROS Answers with karma: 110 on 2015-09-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try the rasberry pi cam or any other usb webcam

---

Originally posted by [duck-development](https://answers.ros.org/users/22870/duck-development/) with karma: 1999 on 2015-09-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Vinh K](https://answers.ros.org/users/23017/vinh-k/) on 2015-09-23**:
thanks. let me look into it. and ill get back to you asap.

**Comment by [Vinh K](https://answers.ros.org/users/23017/vinh-k/) on 2015-09-25**:
thank you for your help